# Javascript Array map "appears" to execute callback on missing elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

Map doesn't get executed on the following array.

`Array(100).map(function(e,i){return i+1;});`

```js
console.log(Array(100).map(function(e, i) {
  return i + 1;
}));
```

I assume because all elements of the array are 'missing': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

However, map gets executed on all elements in the following:

`Array.apply(null,Array(100)).map(function(e,i){return i+1;});`

```js
console.log(Array.apply(null, Array(100)).map(function(e, i) {
  return i + 1;
}));
```

How is it in the second example, the elements of the array change from 'missing' to 'undefined'? (at least I assume that is what is happening.)

Comment: because you instantiate the outer array with 100 undefined elements. `console.log(Array.apply(null,Array(100)))` you can use `String` or `Object` as well, or the new `Array.from()`. in short, using apply() is like manually passing all those elements to the Array constructor, undefined in value or not, they will appear in the output array, the same as in `Array(undefined, undefined, undefined)`

Comment: think of the diff when you apply() something like these as arrays:  `{0:123,1:234,length:2}` vs `{length: 99}` one has a few properties, one only has 1(which would be hidden in a real array)...

Comment: The key here is the `.apply` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply so the array has 100 in its constuctor and they are undefined in value although present

Comment: In ES6 you can use `Array(100).fill()`.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss This makes most sense to me. `apply` accepts an array of arguments as its 2nd argument, so it will treat each element in the array its passed as an individual element, e.g. `Array.apply(null,[,,,,,])` will create an array with undefined - not missing elements. Map works on the resulting array.

Comment: Yes, different ways to explain the same thing basically

Comment: Ha, yes, @MarkSchultheiss. When I said "This makes most sense to me", I was referring to your comment as making most sense to me. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your call

```
Array.apply(null,Array(100)).map(function(e,i){return i+1;});
```

the `Array` function is called with 100 arguments (in fact, the length of `Array(100)` is 100). But when accessing the arguments, all of them are undefined.

If you would call some arbitrary function `func(a, b)` like this:

```
func.apply(null, Array(2))
```

The parameters `a` and `b` will be undefined and the length of `arguments` will be 2.

`map()` iterates over the elements in the array but there are actually no elements! However, the array has length 100. This is weird but this is the way arrays behave in JS. If you use the array as an argument list for a function (via `.apply()`), the arguments are accessed and become `undefined`. The original array does not change, but accessing an index in the empty array yields `undefined`.

Comment: But why does creating an array with a length of `100` (`Array(100)`) not work but creating an array by passing in 100 values (`Array(undefined, undefined, ..., undefined)` a.k.a `Array.apply(null, Array(100))`) map correctly?

Comment: [].map expects each `(index in array)` to be true, passing a number to the constructor doesn't cause that to happen, but specifiying a value (even undefined) does. if the index of an element is not "in array", then map skips that element. look at a [].map() polyfill for details. also note that underscore's `_.map`  _would_ iterate the "empty" elements; heads up!

Comment: Extended the answer.

Comment: Yes, it all seems to be the way apply treats the array it receives in it's second argument, filling them as `undefined` if they are missing, e.g. `Array.apply(null,[,,,,,])`

Answer (score 2):

Let's see how [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) defines "missing":

> It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes
>   that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never
>   been assigned a value).

Internally, this is done with [[[HasProperty]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.6). You can use the [`in` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.7) to check [[HasProperty]] manually.

And now see the difference:

```js
var arr = Array(100);
'0' in arr; // false
```

```js
var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(100));
'0' in arr; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

The main question is "Why Array(100) is an empty array with length equal 100 and Array.apply(null, Array(100)) is an array with 100 empty values?"

To answer that we need to go to the standard. Precisely, [Standard ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), sections [22.1.1.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-len), [22.1.1.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-items), [19.2.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.apply) and [7.3.17](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-createlistfromarraylike). I'll quote it here:

> 22.1.1.2 Array (len)
>
> This description applies if and only if the Array constructor is
>   called with exactly one argument.
>
> ```
> 1. Let numberOfArgs be the number of arguments passed to this function call.
> 2. Assert: numberOfArgs = 1.
> 3. If NewTarget is undefined, let newTarget be the active function object, else let newTarget be NewTarget.
> 4. Let proto be GetPrototypeFromConstructor(newTarget, "%ArrayPrototype%").
> 5. ReturnIfAbrupt(proto).
> 6. Let array be ArrayCreate(0, proto).
> 7. If Type(len) is not Number, then
>       Let defineStatus be CreateDataProperty(array, "0", len).
>       Assert: defineStatus is true.
>       Let intLen be 1.
> 8. Else,
>       Let intLen be ToUint32(len).
>       If intLen ≠ len, throw a RangeError exception.
> 9. Let setStatus be Set(array, "length", intLen, true).
> 10. Assert: setStatus is not an abrupt completion.
> 11. Return array.
> ```
>
> 22.1.1.3 Array (...items )
>
> This description applies if and only if the Array constructor is
>   called with at least two arguments.
>
> When the Array function is called the following steps are taken:
>
> ```
> 1. Let numberOfArgs be the number of arguments passed to this function call.
> 2. Assert: numberOfArgs ≥ 2.
> 3. If NewTarget is undefined, let newTarget be the active function object, else let newTarget be NewTarget.
> 4. Let proto be GetPrototypeFromConstructor(newTarget, "%ArrayPrototype%").
> 5. ReturnIfAbrupt(proto).
> 6. Let array be ArrayCreate(numberOfArgs, proto).
> 7. ReturnIfAbrupt(array).
> 8. Let k be 0.
> 9. Let items be a zero-origined List containing the argument items in order.
> 10. Repeat, while k < numberOfArgs
>       Let Pk be ToString(k).
>       Let itemK be items[k].
>       Let defineStatus be CreateDataProperty(array, Pk, itemK).
>       Assert: defineStatus is true.
>       Increase k by 1.
> 11. Assert: the value of array’s length property is numberOfArgs.
> 12. Return array.
> ```
>
> 19.2.3.1 Function.prototype.apply ( thisArg, argArray )
>
> When the apply method is called on an object func with arguments
>   thisArg and argArray, the following steps are taken:
>
> ```
> 1. If IsCallable(func) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 2. If argArray is null or undefined, then
>       Return Call(func, thisArg).
> 3. Let argList be CreateListFromArrayLike(argArray).
> 4. ReturnIfAbrupt(argList ).
> 5. Perform PrepareForTailCall().
> 6. Return Call(func, thisArg, argList).
> ```
>
> 7.3.17 CreateListFromArrayLike (obj [, elementTypes] )
>
> The abstract operation CreateListFromArrayLike is used to create a
>   List value whose elements are provided by the indexed properties of an
>   array-like object, obj. The optional argument elementTypes is a List
>   containing the names of ECMAScript Language Types that are allowed for
>   element values of the List that is created. This abstract operation
>   performs the following steps:
>
> ```
> 1. ReturnIfAbrupt(obj).
> 2. If elementTypes was not passed, let elementTypes be (Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Symbol, Number, Object).
> 3. If Type(obj) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. Let len be ToLength(Get(obj, "length")).
> 5. ReturnIfAbrupt(len).
> 6. Let list be an empty List.
> 7. Let index be 0.
> 8. Repeat while index < len
>       Let indexName be ToString(index).
>       Let next be Get(obj, indexName).
>       ReturnIfAbrupt(next).
>       If Type(next) is not an element of elementTypes, throw a TypeError exception.
>       Append next as the last element of list.
>       Set index to index + 1.
> 9. Return list.
> ```

As you can see, there is plenty of work going here. In short, when Array(100) executes it produces an array-like object with property `length` equal to 100, but there is no objects inside that Array. But, if you'll try to get any, it will return `undefined` for any indexes. Because of that, when `CreateListFromArrayLike` executes, it gets all 100 `undefined` values from array-like object provided and returns actual List with 100 `undefined` values in it, which goes to the `Array(...items)` function.