# Iterate over Array with empty elements (ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, undefined

I have an array with a specified length and I'm trying to populate it with values that are dependent on each index.

```
let arr = new Array(someLength)
arr.map((v, i) => i * 2)
```

From what I know, this isn't working because `map` *skips* undefined values.

I have a few questions:

1. Why does `map` work on something like `[undefined, undefined]`?
2. Is there anyway to accomplish this using ES6 array methods?

   I know I can use a standard `for` loop, but was wondering if there's a *nicer* way to do it.

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
      arr[i] = i * 2 
   }
   ```

   I've found one method so far, it's not really clean though.

   ```
   arr = arr.fill(undefined).map((foo, i) => i * 2)
   ```

Comment: Have you tried anything with every()?

Comment: `.map()` doesn't skip undefined values; it skips undefined properties/members.

Comment: `[...Array(someLength)].map((_, i) => i * 2)` is another possibility.

Comment: It is more correct to say that `map` skips **missing** elements, or **holes**. By the way, no need to say `fill(undefined)`--just `fill()` is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Array map “appears” to execute callback on missing elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35044451/1529630) and [JavaScript “new Array(n)” and “Array.prototype.map” weirdness](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5501581/1529630)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. Why does `.map` work on something like `[undefined, undefined]`?

Consider these two scenarios

```
let a1 = [];
a1.length = 2;
a1; // [undefined × 2]

// vs

let a2 = [undefined, undefined];
a2; // [undefined, undefined]
```

What would be the result of `Object.keys` on each of these?

```
Object.keys(a1); // []
Object.keys(a2); // ["0", "1"]
```

So, we can see the difference between the two - one has initialised keys, the other doesn't

---

> 2. Is there anyway to accomplish this using ES6 array methods?

You already pointed out `.fill`, you could also use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
Array.from({length: 5}, (itm, idx) => 2 * idx); // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I think you should change last statement to use original `arr`ay

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an array with `undefined` values.

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 5})
```

and use it for the mapping.

```js
var array = Array.apply(null, {length: 5});
console.log(array);

array = array.map((_, i) => 2 * i);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: If you change `var array = Array.apply(...` with `var array = []; array.length = 5;` then you'll see it's not working.

Comment: @mortezaT, right. but i use the above without sparsed elements.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to fill the array with 0. Then you could process with map or forEach like this :

```
var arr = new Array(5); //[,,,,,]
arr.fill(0).forEach((v, i, tab) => {tab[i] = i * 2}); // [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```